# QT/C++ - Accessing MainWindow UI from a different class

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a beginner to both C++ and Qt, so perhaps this is trivial. It certainly feels like it should be simple, but I've been searching for an answer for a few hours now and can't find the solution. I'm making a simple board game where the MainWindow's ui (made in QtDesigner) contains a canvas for the game board (a QGraphicsView). Now, the main.cpp is as simple as can be:

```
MainWindow Game;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 QApplication a(argc, argv);

 Game.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

Since I need to access and edit the MainWindow Widgets from another totally unrelated class, I thought the easiest way would be to just make MainWindow a global variable. It seems that this approach was very wrong, though. Upon trying to run the project in QtDesigner I get a Microsoft Visual C++ runtime library error: the application has requested runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

So what is the correct way to do what I need?

Aside from the MainWindow I have a dialog for a new game (QDialog, generated from QtDesigner) that is displayed after clicking a menu item in MainWindow. When the user inputs all parameters for the game and clicks OK in the dialog, I instantiate a custom non-Qt class called GameState. This class is meant to operate the game itself, draw the board, prompt the user, etc. However, as this class is created in the QDialog, it does not know of the existence of a MainWindow and so I cannot do anything with the MainWindow from this class. How can I modify the MainWindow from an unrelated class, then?

Also, jsut how does the setEnabled() function work? It never seems to do anything. Any widget I set as disabled in the QtDesigner and then try to enable through this function still stays disabled in the GUI...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54577124/3096593

Answer (score 16):

First off it's a bad idea to create `MainGame` before you create your `QApplication` object.
If you want to have your `MainGame` object globally available like this it should be a pointer:

```
MainWindow *Game;
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication a (argc, argv);

  Game = new MainWindow();
  Game->show();

  int result = a.exec();

  delete Game;
  Game = NULL;

  return result;
}
```

This approach is however not the most elegant. There are two much better choices.

1. The `QApplication` object actually stores all top level windows like your `MainGame` which means you can allways aquire it through `QApplication::topLevelWidgets()` which is a static function and returns a list with all top level widgets. Since you only have one, the first one is your `MainGame`. The drawback is you'll have to cast it, but using Qts `qobject_cast<MainGame*>(...)` is fairly safe. You'll have to check the result though to make sure it isn't a NULL pointer.
2. Use the singelton design pattern. You should store the global Game pointer in the source (cpp) file of the Game class itself (subclass `QMainWindow`) and your Game class should implement a static public method which returns this global pointer. So if any other class needs the `Game` pointer, it simply calls:

   ```
   MyGame *theGame = MyGame::getInstance();
   ```

   for example.

Regarding your `setEnabled()` problem. Please post the relevant code. If it's too much feel free to send me the *.ui file and the piece of code via mail.

Best regards
D

Answer (score 9):

I am doing it this way:

```
QMainWindow* getMainWindow()
{
    foreach (QWidget *w, qApp->topLevelWidgets())
        if (QMainWindow* mainWin = qobject_cast<QMainWindow*>(w))
            return mainWin;
    return nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If your application has only one window you can simply use:

```
MainWindow * win = (MainWindow *) qApp::activeWindow();
```

Comment: Don't use C-style cast in C++. Use `qobject_cast` or `static_cast` instead.

Comment: `static_cast<MainWindow*>(parent())->theMethodYouWantToCall();`

Comment: Also, this approach will not work, if MainWindow doesn't have the keyboard focus = if it is not active.

Comment: For reference, now In Qt5, this is `QApplication::activeWindow()`.

Comment: This approach fails in too many cases so it should not be used. If the main window does not have keyboard focus (e.g. after being brough up by clicking on task bar), then `qApp::activeWindow()` returns nullptr.

Comment: static_cast<MainWindow*>(parent())->statusBar()->showMessage("mousemove");

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: did you mean to say "`qobject_cast` or `dynamic_cast`"? I don't see how `static_cast` is better than C-style cast in this example.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to do this is to first set up a signal in the header file of your other class to say perform a function to manipulate an object in the main class like this

```
signals:
    void disableLoadButtton();
```

Then create a slot under private slots in the header file of the main window like this

```
private slots:
     void disableLoadButtton();
```

Then create the function as a members function in the main window to manipulate the object

```
void MainWindow::disableLoadButton()
{
     ui->loadButton->setenabled(false);
}
```

Then add the following line in another member function of the main window which say sets up the page. My other class is called searchWidget

```
void MainWindow::setUpPage()
{
    connect(searchWidget, SIGNAL(disableLoadButton()), this, SLOT(disableLoadButton()));
}
```

Then all you have to do to disable the loadButton (which is a object in MainWindow) is to add the following line in any members function of my other class searchWidget

```
void searchWidget::performSomething()
{
      emit disableLoadButton();
}
```

This will then manipulate the object loadButton in the mainwindow from within a member function of the other class searchWidget.

Comment: How to create searchWidget object?

Answer (score 2):

In the past I used approach described in this answer (found in [Qtractor](https://github.com/rncbc/qtractor) project).

Now I use QObject 'name' property and discover it anywhere as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54577124/3096593).

main.c

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "c.h"

MainWindow * MainWindow::pMainWindow = nullptr;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    pMainWindow = this;
    setCentralWidget(&m_pb);
    connect(&m_pb, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_pb_clicked()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {delete ui;}

// kind of singleton reference.
MainWindow *MainWindow::getMainWinPtr()
{
    return pMainWindow;
}

void MainWindow::pbSetText()
{
    m_pb.setText(QString{"Call from c."});
}

void MainWindow::on_pb_clicked()
{
    c C;  // call of MainWindow from class c ctor
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QString>
#include <QPushButton>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    static MainWindow * getMainWinPtr();
    void pbSetText();

public slots:
    void on_pb_clicked();

private:
    static MainWindow * pMainWindow;

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QPushButton m_pb{QString{"Press me."}, this};
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

c.cpp

```
#include "c.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

c::c()
{
    MainWindow * mw = MainWindow::getMainWinPtr();
    mw->pbSetText();
}
```

c.h

```
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

class c
{
public:
    explicit c();
};

#endif // C_H
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to access your MainWindow from another window, you are probably doing it wrong. Using another class to pass information with signals/slots is probably a much better approach

Comment: If we need to the observer design pattern, we need to pass the view(MainWindow) to controller class so cotoller can access its' method.

Comment: **Ah, yes.** The inevitable "You're doing it wrong!" non-answer. There are perfectly valid reasons to directly access a singleton main window. Parental finger wagging is rarely a helpful response. This is no exception. We're all responsible adults here.