# QT c++ internal variable handover

Tags: c++, qt, variables, input

I have declared an int function in mainwindow.h

```
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    int port();
```

furthermore I declared this function in the appendant mainwindow.cpp file.

```
int MainWindow::port()
{
    int port_int;
    QString port_ei;

    if(ui->portInput->text() == 0)
    {
        port_ei = "6008";
        ui->textIncome->setPlainText(port_ei);
        port_int = port_ei.toInt();
    }
    else
    {
        port_ei = ui->portInput->text();
        ui->textIncome->setPlainText(port_ei);
        port_int = port_ei.toInt();
    }

    return port_int;
}
```

now i want my server (in the myserver.cpp file) to listen to that port.

```
MyServer::MyServer(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    server = new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(server,SIGNAL(newConnection()),this,SLOT(newConnection()));

    int port_out =  MainWindow::port();

    if(!server->listen(QHostAddress::Any,port_out))
    {

        qDebug() << "Server could not start.";

    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Server started.";
    }
}
```

but qt tells me that i made an illegal request on a not static function (on the `int port_out =  MainWindow::port();`  line).
how to solve that? and is there a better way to do this, if you got two seperate .cpp and .h files (besides the main.cpp).
yes i included "mainwindow.h" and "myserver.h" in both cpp files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MainWindow::port();` is a static function call. But `port` function is not static, it needs to be called like `main_window->port()` where `main_window`is a pointer to a `MainWindow` object.

Comment: how can i create a main_window pointer to MainWindow? *main_window = MainWindow ?

Comment: @beary: No. Take one step back. **Which** MainWindow? If your app only has one, [use the appropriate qApp function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5921594/15416)

Comment: @beary: This is very general question. Are you not familiar with C++ at all? May be you should read some tutorials of books. Usually in Qt an object of main window class is created in `main()` function. Inside main window constructor and class member functions you have a pointer to `MainWindow` that can be referred to using `this` keyword. You can pass this pointer to `MyServer` constructor, for example.

Comment: @MSalters: using `qApp` in such a simple case is bad practice. The pointer should be passed manually. Dependency injection is better than singleton.

Comment: @Riateche: Matter of opinion. Passing around a pointer to a singleton is definitely not better than a straightforward singleton. Furthermore, it is always a good idea to stick with local custom. In the Qt case, that custom is the singleton `qApp`