# Qt sending Object from a form to mainwindow

Tags: c++, qt

I have an assignment and I'm not too sure on how to approach it,at the moment I have 2 window.
-> MainWindow and PlayerForm.

From a menu, I call PlayerFrom and with this form I create a object player.
My question is How can I send back this object to a label in my main window ?

Player Slot :

```
     void MainWindow::on_actionJoueur_triggered()
        {
            FormulaireJoueur *fj = new FormulaireJoueur;
            fj->show();

        }
```

Form OK Slot :

```
void FormulaireJoueur::on_OkJoueur_clicked()
{
    try
    {
        std::string Nom = (ui->J_Nom->text()).toStdString();
        std::string  Prenom = (ui->J_Prenom->text()).toStdString();
        std::string Telephone = (ui->J_Phone->text()).toStdString();
        std::string  Position = (ui->J_Pos->text()).toStdString();
        QDate  Date = ui->J_Date->date();

        int jour = Date.day();
        int mois = Date.month();
        int annee = Date.year();

        util::Date DateJoueur(jour,mois,annee);

        Joueur NouveauJoueur(Nom,Prenom,DateJoueur,Telephone,Position);
        std::string Message = NouveauJoueur.reqPersonneFormate();
    }

    catch(ContratException e)
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Erreur","Erreur lors de la création du joueur.");
    }

}
```

FormulaireJoueur.h :

```
#ifndef FORMULAIREJOUEUR_H
#define FORMULAIREJOUEUR_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class FormulaireJoueur;
}

class FormulaireJoueur : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FormulaireJoueur(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~FormulaireJoueur();

private slots:
    void on_OkJoueur_clicked();

    void on_AnnulerJoueur_clicked();

private:
    Ui::FormulaireJoueur *ui;
};

#endif // FORMULAIREJOUEUR_H
```

Container :

```
Annuaire AnnuairePrincipal("Canadiens");
AnnuairePrincipal.AjouterPersonne(NouveauJoueur);
```

Comment: possbile duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920527/qt-c-accessing-mainwindow-ui-from-a-different-class?rq=1

Comment: what object do you need to get ? Joueur or the  std::string

Comment: Joueur sorry the string was a test from earlier

Comment: can you post your FormulaireJoueur.h and the container in which you stock the Joueur in your Mainwindows ?

Comment: The container is a custom class

Comment: For what reason didn't you have `FormulaireJoueur.h` included in `MainWindow.h`?

Answer (score 0):

edit : FormulaireJoueur should inherits from QDialog as it is a dialog
edit again : closeEvent forgotten

add Joueur at your FormulaireJoueur class, and add a public getter to it 
I assumed that you use directly the Joueur type and that the copy constructor is correct

```
Joueur FormulaireJoueur::getJoueur()
{
  return this->_joueur;
}
```

in your MainWindow.h add a slot

```
void FomulaireJoueurFinished(int return)
```

then in your player slot :

```
 void MainWindow::on_actionJoueur_triggered()
    {
        FormulaireJoueur *fj = new FormulaireJoueur;
        connect(fj, SIGNAL(finished ( int)), this, SLOT(FomulaireJoueurFinished(int return));
        fj->show();

    }
```

then  in MainWindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::FomulaireJoueurFinished(int return)
{
   if (return == QDialog::Accepted)
   this->AnnuairePrincipal.AjouterPersonne((static_cast<FormulaireJoueur *>(sender))->getJoueur());
}
```

you also should override closeEvent of the FormulaireJoueur Dialog

```
void QDialog::closeEvent ( QCloseEvent * e ) [virtual protected]
```

to integrate your verification and generation of Joueur

Comment: Doesn't seem to work would it be easier to send my variable to my main window ?

Comment: you can also yes in your slot FormulaireJoueur *fj = new FormulaireJoueur(this);
and add a MainWindow * _parent in your FormulaireJoueur class, then 
in your ctor use _parent(parent)
and you'lle ba able to call public members

Comment: Him not to sure on how to add a MainWindow * _parent