# How to access QMainWindow from a QWidget which parent is not QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qmainwindow

I am programming a GUI with Qt Creator (Qt5.10) under OSX. I have a `QMainWindow` for the main app's window. Inside this I have a `QTab` widget, in which I have entire widget (let's call it `CaptureTabWidget` which contains some additional widgets AND a `QFrame` (the parent of this `QFrame` is the `QTab`). In this last widget I will be drawing some stuff. The point is that I would like to write in the `statusBar` of the `QMainWindow` some values related to the position of the mouse in that `QFrame`, but I do not have any idea about how to access the main window from a method inside the `CaptureTabWidget` which contains the `QFrame`.

The whole picture goes like this:

```
                 X
+-----------+  XXX
|MainWindow | XXXXXXXXX
+-----+-----+  XXX    XXXXXX
      |          X         XXX
+-----v------------+          XX
|QTabWidget        |           XX
|No parent         |            XX
+-----+------------+             XX
      |                           X
+-----v-------------+          ?? X
|CaptureTabQWidget  |             X
|Parent:QTabWidget  |             X
+-----+-------------+            X
      |                         X
+-----v-------------+         XX
|QFrame             |    XXXXXX
|Parent:CaptureTab  | XXX
+-------------------+
```

I have tried modifying the CaptureTabWidget's constructor in order to receive a `QMainWindow*` which points to the main window, but it seems Qt Creator doesn't allow custom constructors when promoting widgets in the Designer. I am wondering what is the right way to do this.

Comment: Does this work https://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2013/11/27/get-mainwindow-qt/ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QT/C++ - Accessing MainWindow UI from a different class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920527/qt-c-accessing-mainwindow-ui-from-a-different-class)

Comment: Thanks by the feedback. Yes, i saw that solution, I was just wondering if there's an elegant way to do that, since I'm not an experienced Qt Programmer. I will wait a little bit more, otherwise I will mark the article you gave me as a solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you just aim to write to the `statusBar` of the parent `QMainWindow`, you can post a [`QStatusTipEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatustipevent.html#details) to any child of your `QMainWindow`, and the event will keep propagating to the parent `QWidget`s until it reaches the main window where it gets handled by by changing the content in the status bar. In other words, something like this in your `QFrame` does the job:

```
QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, new QStatusTipEvent("your tip"));
//                          ^^^^
//                          assuming this is a pointer to your QFrame object
```

---

As a side note, this is the same way views in Qt (`QTableView`, `QTreeView`, `QListView`, ...) are able to change status tips (when their models provide a custom value for the role [`Qt::StatusTipRole`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)) while they might be buried deep down in the `QObject` tree...

---

For purposes other than just writing to the `statusBar` of a parent `QMainWindow`, I would try to generalize the above approach by having a custom `QEvent` (i.e. one that has a value between `QEvent::User` and `QEvent::MaxUser`)  and handle that event in my `QMainWindow` subclass appropriately. I find this way much cleaner and more maintainable than other solutions that depend on global variables/singletons (that keep track of your supposedly one `QMainWindow` instance).