# Accessing a class from another class Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have two classes (mainwindow & class1) which are not connected so object of each other are not created in the classes. I want to access ui elements in mainwindow from class1. I tried to use signal&slot but to do this, I had to create an object of class1 in mainwindow. Any suggestion for this problem? One idea is writing address of mainwindow object to a text file and reading it to point this address from class1. Can this be solution?
If yes, how can I do it? I tried following code to test but not work.

```
MainWindow *mainObject = 0x7fffa9574290;
```

Comment: Please can you clarify the question and why you cant have an object of class1 inside your mainwindow?

Comment: @TCouch I can, but if I create new object in mainwindow, there will be two class1 objects. and I need properties of first one, not the one in mainwindow.

Comment: Never try to assign a literal address value to a pointer. It's almost guaranteed to be mistaken at some point. And generally, if `mainwindow` uses `class1` functionality, it should be a member of it, unless you need to have class1 outside of mainwindow as well. You can pass your object of `class1` as a reference in that case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QT/C++ - Accessing MainWindow UI from a different class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920527/qt-c-accessing-mainwindow-ui-from-a-different-class)

Comment: May be you are targeting the problem from a wrong angle. What is you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell one class about the other. So if class1 is created before mainwindow then pass it as argument to the constructor. If it i created later then why not create it in mainwindow and later get a reference to class1 from mainwindow instead of creating a second instance. Or make class1 a global / singleton. That way anyone can ask for the one instance of class1 and first one can create it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to access ui elements in mainwindow from class1

No, you don't. The ui elements in `mainwindow` are implementation details. They are of no concern to other classes. The interface should be general and not tied to the ui elements and should reflect the functionality, not the implementation. Say that the `mainwindow` is providing UI for some text. You'd want to notify anyone who cares that the text was indeed changed. Thus:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT
  Ui::MainWindow ui;
  ...
public:
  Q_SIGNAL void myTextChanged(const QString &);
  QString myText() const { return ui.myTextWidget->text(); }
  ...
};
```

Then, `class1` should have a way of being notified what the text is:

```
class Class1 : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  ...
public:
  Q_SLOT void setMyText(const QString &);
  ...
};
```

The only place that has information about both classes is the body of `main` (or a similar function, or an injection dependency framework), and that's where the connections belong - after all, that's where you make the text passing concrete and no more an abstract operation: you tie `Class1` and `MainWindow` outside of them, minimizing their coupling:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWindow win;
  Class1 obj;
  connect(&win, &MainWindow::myTextChanged, &obj, &Class1::setMyText);
  obj.setMyText(win.myText());
  win.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Of course, if you don't like all of it sitting in the poor body of `main` (why?), you can relegate it all to a class that represents the composition of the primary objects of the application:

```
class AppComposition {
  MainWindow win;
  Class1 obj;
  ...
public:
  AppComposition() {
    connect(&win, &MainWindow::myTextChanged, &obj, &Class1::setMyText);
    obj.setMyText(win.myText());
    ...
  }
  void show() {
    win.show();
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  AppComposition comp;
  comp.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

But at that point you probably could use a lightweight dependency injection framework. Or at least consider it by learning how they work and how to use them.