# Using Qt mainwindow object separately or as class member of applications' class

Tags: c++, qt

A theoretical question: in Qt examples, an object of QMainWindow class is always (at least in the examples I've seen so far) used to create a separate variable in main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I'm quite new to application development in general and C++ particularily, but to me it seems like having a mainwindow object as a member of app's class might be more convenient to access main window's methods from somewhere, something like that:

```
class MyApp: public QApplication
{
    QMainWindow* mainWindow;
    void someMethod();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MyApp app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow app.mainWindow = new QMainWindow;
    app.mainWindow->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

and then somewhere inside the app:

```
#define theApp (static_cast<MyApp*>(QCoreApplication::instance()))
theApp->mainWindow->someMethod();
```

Does it make sense, what are pros and cons of this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you made typo here:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MyApp app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow mainWindow = new QMainWindow;
    app.mainWindow->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Your `mainWindow` is a local variable here, but then you are accessing to the `app.mainWindow` member. Furthermore, the `mainWindow` has incompatible type -- not a pointer.

Then, you are allocating the object of `QMainWindow` in the heap, but are not deleting it. Though, this is happening in the `main` function and this object will be deleted automatically, but this is a classical memory leakage.

As for your question: technically, this is not prohibited. But, the `QApplication` and `QMainWindow` are intended for different purposes. The main goal of the first is to handle the events, while the second is the GUI class. Application may work without GUI, in general.

The goal of your question was already elucidated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920527/qt-c-accessing-mainwindow-ui-from-a-different-class), for example.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and for the link. I couldn't find it