# C++ Qt GUI application architecture and module interfaces

Tags: c++, qt, oop, hierarchy, signals-slots

I am working on an application to manipulate simple graphical geometry with associated attributes for several regions organized in a parent child relationship, e.g. there could be three super elements each containing two regions with the graphical elements. I am building this with Qt using a QGraphicsScene for the layout inside the applications QMainWindow, and a seperate window to manage the graphical elements in each region.

It is currently setup in a way where a *Layout* class sets up the *supers* and the *supers* create their *regions* and the *Manager* class that controls graphical elements and the seperate window.

To add another case, each *region* also may create a TCP client to connect to some server and receive messages to be displayed graphically, and this *client* could encounter an error which currently is displayed using a static QMessageBox method.

Generally speaking, I am mixing custom classes with Qt classes in an object hierarchy where child elements sometimes need to access the root parent around which the GUI is based (MainWindow).

- Since many of these objects need to access the QGraphicsScene, I currently use a mix of accessing it via a number of parent() calls or by passing the scene's pointer.
- I sometimes use Qt's signal-slot mechanism in attempt to create better separation through interfaces, but this creates overhead (and I am not sure what the advantages are [except for thread safety] compared to calling methods via object reference)
- Not all objects in the hierarchy inherit QWidget, so the "parent" reference does not always work e.g. for the QMessageBox modality

I know this is a vague question but I am only looking for general hints on how objects in a typical GUI hierarchy are supposed to interact and how Qt's Signal-Slot mechanism is used best.

Should I always pass a reference to MainWindow in my classes? Should I keep that reference globally? Should children e.g. not display message boxes but emit a signal for the MainWindow to show (but then how would the child get the user input?)?

What is this problem generally called?

Comment: Apparently, one way to access the main window is `qApp->mainWidget()` which could resolve the window mode problem. But I'm not sure this is better than a global pointer variable. Also, it does not clarify any of the structural problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54577124/3096593