# Is it OK to chain signals and slots several times?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals

I have something like the following design of classes and I'm wondering if it's OK that I use many signal slot connections to communicate between them. There is a `MainWindow` class which holds all the GUI, then a `Wrapper` class, which provides an interface to the back-end, then there is a `Controller` class for spawning and managing threads and finally there are `Worker`s which do all the work.

Now let's say I'm loading a file and want to display progress using a progress bar in the `MainWindow`. My `Worker` class sends `updateProgress(int progress)` to `Controller::handleProgress(int progress)` slot which again sends progress signal to the `Wrapper` class, which in return sends a progress signal to the main window, which finally updates the progress bar.

Similarly when the data has been loaded it is processed in the `Wrapper` class and, again, communicated through signals and slots (although with one less step).

Is it a standard way of doing things in Qt or should I rethink my design?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54577124/3096593

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a valid possibility.

Note that Qt allows you to go even further and do the following:

```
QObject::connect(&sender, SIGNAL(mySenderSignal(int)),
                 &receiver, SIGNAL(myReceiverSignal(int));
```

That's right, you can bind a signal to a signal. All it does can be seen as "**when the sender's signal is emitted, emit the receiver's signal**".

If you don't have any specific task to perform in your intermediary slots, that might save you a few lines, while showing exactly what you're doing: you're "forwarding" a signal. Otherwise, if you must absolutely do work in between, then you must keep the signals and the slots.

Note that you still have to be sure that the signals signatures match.